# Changing activity menu when the fragment changed

Tags: android

I am having a `MainActivity` with three tabs using `ViewPager` and PagerSlidingTabStrip library in my android app.

The problem is how can i change the menu of `MainActivity` when the fragment changed(i.e. Tab changed).

Each Tab has different menu. How can i do this?

Comment: share your code here to help you in a better manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override **onCreateOptionsMenu** in each fragment used in ViewPager and use menu.clear() before inflating menu resource.

You can check how to use this in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Attempt on "Changing menu items at runtime" chapter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using 2 fragments...you're just going to add one

1. fragment

   ...

   ```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {


       final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
   ```

   ...

It connects to layout ***login***

2. fragment is basically the same except the layout

   ...
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ```
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register, container, false);
   ...
   ```

   It connects to layout ***register***

Then we have TabsPagerAdapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // 1 fragment activity
            return new LoginFragment();
        case 1:
            // 2 fragment activity
            return new RegisterFragment();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

And all that you call here, in MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener,ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private String[] tabs = { "1.Fragment", "2.Fragment"};

    private TabHost.TabContentFactory mTabFactory = new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(MainActivity.this);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            return v;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_bottomtabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        for (String tab_name : tabs){
            TabHost.TabSpec spec =mTabHost.newTabSpec(tab_name);
            spec.setIndicator(tab_name);
            spec.setContent(mTabFactory);
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = -1;
        if (tabId.contains("1.Fragment")) {
            position = 0;
        } else if (tabId.contains("2.Fragment")) {
            position = 1;
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


}
```

I hope this helped